# Calling dumpbin from C# not recognized?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging

I am trying to use dumpbin (which I saw from another SO post is installed with Visual Studio) to disassemble a .exe from C#. However, I get an error saying

> dumpbin is not recognized as an internal or external command

1. Why is it not recognized if dumpbin comes with Visual Studio?
2. Once this is recognised, how could I output to a string, rather than a file?

I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Objdump
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo ProcessInfo;
            Process Process;

            ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/K " + "dumpbin /DISASM /out:log.txt MyExe.exe");
            ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

            Process = Process.Start(ProcessInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path to `dumpbin.exe` needs to be on the `PATH` environment variable otherwise you'll need to supply the full path yourself.

For me it happens to be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin`.